# Date fields size (in all occurance) is larger than all other fields in column in ASP.Net

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have created one application by using ASP.Net. Here my problem is Date input field in aligning correctly in Firefox but in Chrome it is displaying bigger than all other text boxes. 
Here is the code for Date Field,

```
<div class="input-group date form_date dob" data-date="" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" style="width:176%">
<input class="form-control" tabindex="5" size="12" @*required="required"*@ data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" type="text" id="txtDOB" data-bind="date:DOB,value:DOB" @*readonly*@>
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span></div>
 <input type="[enter image description here][1]hidden" id="dtp_input2" data-bind="value:DOB" /><br /
```

[image]

I have attached the screen shots of both browsers output. Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

In face, there is no way but to keep that. Each browser could render HTML elements in different manners. So you have two options:

1- Use a date plugin. It will make your app look like the same in any browsers.

2- Set the height of all boxes to the largest rendered version.

Comment: I am happy for that. So please vote up if you found it useful.